# CSS Grid FullScreen

Tags: css

Mi duda es acerca de cómo crear un área con css grid layout que ocupe la pantalla completa, es decir, como si le diese un `height:100vh`, y un `width:100vw`.

Estoy intentando darle el número de ROWS a un slider para que me ocupe justo la pantalla, pero en la especificación de css grid layout no encuentro nada específico ( valga la redundancia). Tampoco creando un grid area de 100vh, ya que supongo que las grid-areas no tienen esos valores como predeterminados.

Lo único que consigo es darle unos valores al contenedor, pero no es adaptable, ya que no es la medida en proporciones de pantalla, sino de columnas y filas. ¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo o si aún no existe ningún valor al respecto?

Comment: No se si entiendo exactamente lo que necesitas pero esta publicación te puede sacar da dudas
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747185/force-css-grid-container-to-fill-full-screen-of-device

Comment: Debes mostrar el código que tienes para poderte ayudar, **es importante que leas [ask]**, saludos

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es exactamente lo que intentas hacer, pero si tratas de hacer un slider con bootstrap que ocupe la pantalla completa y que sea responsive para todas las pantallas, te dejo un código que yo tengo hecho a ver si te sirve:

**Código HTML**

```
        <div class="slidertv">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
              </ol>
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="assets/rsc/publicidadtv/slider1.jpg" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="assets/rsc/publicidadtv/slider2.jpg" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="assets/rsc/publicidadtv/slider3.jpg" alt="...">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Código CSS**

```
.slidertv .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.slidertv .carousel-inner {
    height: 100vh;
}
.slidertv img {
    height: 100vh !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

No sé si he copiado todo el código necesario, en caso de que no te funcione me dices y lo miro.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva.